# Paste content of another file in current file

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is a keyboard shortcut / command name to paste the content of another file into the current file?

I want functionality similar to vim

```
:r inputfile.txt
```

and **inputfile.txt** gets pasted into the current file at the insertion point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you: [Replace File Name With ...](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=espresso3389.insert-file).  One of the options is to replace with the file's content.

You can either trigger it via the context menu or set a keybinding to the command:

```
extension.replaceFileNameWithContent
```

You would have to select the fileName first though.

---

Here is a way to simplify the process if you do this alot.

With another extension to select the previous fileName - using [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) with this in your settings.json:

```
"selectby.regexes": {

  "selectFileName": {
    "backward": "\\s+",        
    "backwardInclude": false,
    "showSelection": true
  }
}
```

and some keybinding to run the selection and replace file command (in keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "alt+s",               // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "selectby.regex",
  "args": ["selectFileName"],
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection && editorLangId == javascript"
},

{
  "key": "alt+s",               //  same keybinding as above
  "command": "extension.replaceFileNameWithContent",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection && editorLangId == javascript"
},
```

Replace `editorLangId  == javascript` with your file langID if you want to limit the keybinding to a particular language or group of languages.

I deliberately chose the same keybinding to make it simple.  The first one runs if you have no selection in the editor and the second runs when you do have a selection - so they essentially run "in sequence" when you type <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> twice.  Demo (you do have to press your keybinding twice - the gif didn't capture both for some reason):

[image: replace with file contents demo]

Comment: Worked very well

Comment: This works ; can some one point me to VS CODE cheat sheet for Vim user. How to achive tasks like search replace tasks over range of lines like ":20,25s/dev/prod" is vscode